# How to group by field type for matched document fields?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, resthighlevelclient

I am using term aggregation to count the field values but before to aggregation i am doing filter search based on the result aggregation will work.. finally i need the id's and aggregation count for example
if exception id is 1 and if it get matches then i need output as

1 ->  "key": "transfer"
      "doc_count": 2

2 ->  "key": "stock"
      "doc_count": 4

and i have highlighted the exception id in the below which i want as a pointer to each bucket.

How can i do it in elastic search i have attached the sample response.

```
{
  "took": 250,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "america",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "clusterId": "1",
          "rank": 1,
          "events": [
            {
              "eventId": "1",
              "eventType": "Delayed",
              "metaInfo": {
                "batch_id": "batch_1"
              },
              "recommendationData": [
                {
                  ***"exceptionId": "1",***
                  "item": "Item1",
                  "location": "DC1",
                  "dueDate": "2019-01-10T05:30:00.000+0530",
                  "quantity": 100,
                  "metaInfo": {
                    "batch_id": "batch_1",
                    "dummy_id": "dummy_1"
                  },
                  "rank": 1,
                  "recommendations": [
                    {
                      "rank": 1,
                      "recommendationType": "transfer",
                      "customerName": "Walmart",
                      "stockTransfer": {
                        "primaryRecommendation": true,
                        "priority": 1,
                        "sourceLocation": "DC3",
                        "metaInfo": 40,
                        "shipDate": "2019-01-09T05:30:00.000+0530",
                        "arrivalDate": "2019-01-10T05:30:00.000+0530",
                        "transportMode": "Road",
                        "transferCost": 200.0,
                        "maxQtyAvailableForTransfer": 40,
                        "totalQtyAtSource": 40
                      },
                      "expedite": null
                    },
                    {
                      "rank": 1,
                      "recommendationType": "transfer",
                      "customerName": "Walmart",
                      "stockTransfer": {
                        "primaryRecommendation": true,
                        "priority": 2,
                        "sourceLocation": "DC2",
                        "transferQuantity": 60,
                        "shipDate": "2019-01-09T05:30:00.000+0530",
                        "arrivalDate": "2019-01-10T05:30:00.000+0530",
                        "transportMode": "Road",
                        "transferCost": 600.0,
                        "maxQtyAvailableForTransfer": 100,
                        "totalQtyAtSource": 100
                      },
                      "expedite": null
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "recommendationTypes": {
      "doc_count": 2,
      "recommendationTypes": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "transfer",
            "doc_count": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need java code for above for ealstic search dsl?

Comment: is there any way to do in the elastic search instead of relying on java

Comment: Let me know whether I am understanding your problem correctly. You need count of matched nested objects but in place of it you are getting all nested object count?

Comment: No. along with term bucket i need the id's(exception id)  which are matched and should point to the bucket... ok for example if the id is 1 and if it matches in the document then along with term bucket [key and count] i need this 1 to point to the bucket.. hope you understand

Comment: basically what i need.. for the matched id's i need match id along with term bucket..

Comment: let me know if it is not clear yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to aggregation on any exceptionId or recommendationType , both of which are inside nested objects, you need to use nested aggregation.

Ex. If you have a document with two nested documents with exceptionId as 1 and 2. You want to aggregate on nested document with exceptionId as 2 , you need to use nested aggregation even if you are filtering using nested query in "query" part because entire document is returned even when a nested object matches and you have to specifically mention in aggregation that you want to aggregate on a particular nested object  .
Query

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "recommendations": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "events.recommendationData"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "exception": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "events.recommendationData.exceptionId": [
                "2"
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "exceptionIds": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "events.recommendationData.exceptionId.keyword",
                "size": 10
              },
              "aggs": {
                "recommendations": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "events.recommendationData.recommendations"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "recommendationType": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "events.recommendationData.recommendations.recommendationType",
                        "size": 10
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "recommendations" : {
      "doc_count" : 1,
      "exception" : {
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "exceptionIds" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "2",
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "recommendations" : {
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "recommendationType" : {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                  "buckets" : [
                    {
                      "key" : "transfer",
                      "doc_count" : 2
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```